# How to using Oracle Java SE embedded to work with raspberry sense hat

Tags: java, java-me, raspberry-pi3

I just set up the sense that with my raspberry pi 3, and play around the Python API, which is pretty cool. Is there any official support for Java SE embedded? I couldn't find any doc how to communicate with GPIO or how to using ME version API with SE embedded

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to the article if you not looked yet to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html
I believe its all will help you. At-least I been able to start working reading this when I started first time.

Also, to answer your question, there is no worry about ME etc. Same code which you write with Normal SDK, will work here too.

Comment: Thx for the reply, however, the doc is sort of out of date and more about how to install Java SE on pi, given latest raspbian already have Java pre installed, I'm looking for how to using Java to play with the sensors with sense hat

Comment: To install, can you please check this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk` from your Raspberry-pi console?